# ¿Cómo listar el contenido de una carpeta en Vala?

Tags: rutas, vala

Necesito saber cómo puedo obtener las subcarpetas y archivos que se encuentran en un directorio especificado y guardarlos en un array de tipo string

```
string[] rutas = {};    
string path = "/path/sub_path/folder/";     

File file = File.new_for_path (path);   


/*
 * En esta parte quiero guardar el contenido de la ruta especificada en el array 
 * Ejemplo:
 * /home/user/carpeta
 * /home/user/archivo1
 * /home/user/texto.txt
 * /home/user/otro_texto.txt
 * etc.
 */
```

Comment: Saludos de nuevo, puedes usar el ejemplo de [Glib.Dir](https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.Dir.html) en el valadoc, escribo en una respuesta como podrías implementarlo.

Comment: Gracias, encontré otra manera también aparete. Lo pongo en otro lado porque en los comentarios no aparece como quiero el código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza `GLib.Dir.open (directorio, 0)` para abrir y obtener acceso al directorio, después utiliza un bucle `while` con el método `read_name ()` para obtener la lista de directorios, ejemplo:

```
public static int main (string[] args) {
    try {
        string directorio = "./"; //ruta actual, puedes cambiarlo a la ruta deseada
        var dir = GLib.Dir.open (directorio, 0);
        string? nombre = null;
        string[] rutas = {};

        while ((nombre = dir.read_name ()) != null) {
            rutas += nombre;
        }
    } catch (FileError err) {
        stderr.printf (err.message);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Puedes definir también el tipo de archivo que es, usa el método `FileUtils.test` para obtener la comparación.

```
public static int main (string[] args) {
    try {
        string directorio = "./"; //ruta actual, puedes cambiarlo a la ruta deseada
        var dir = GLib.Dir.open (directorio, 0);
        string? nombre = null;
        string[] rutas = {};

        while ((nombre = dir.read_name ()) != null) {
            string ruta = Path.build_filename (directorio, nombre);
            string tipo = "";

            if (FileUtils.test (ruta, FileTest.IS_REGULAR)) { //si es cualquier archivo
                tipo += "| ARCHIVO ";
                rutas += nombre;
            }

            if (FileUtils.test (ruta, FileTest.IS_SYMLINK)) { //si es un enlace simbolico
                tipo += "| ENLACESIMB ";
                rutas += nombre;
            }

            if (FileUtils.test (ruta, FileTest.IS_DIR)) { //si es una carpeta o subdirectorio
                tipo += "| DIRECTORIO ";
                rutas += nombre;
            }

            if (FileUtils.test (ruta, FileTest.IS_EXECUTABLE)) { //si es un binario o un ejecutable
                tipo += "| EJECUTABLE ";
                rutas += nombre;
            }

            stdout.printf ("%s\t%s\n", nombre, tipo);
        }
    } catch (FileError err) {
        stderr.printf (err.message);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias ;)
una cuestión que se sale del tema. Puedo utilizar "path literales"?
O sea el típico /phat/subpat/*/folder ?

Comment: @Andy-devnix aun no lo he intentado, habrá que hacerlo, solo he utilizado rutas estáticas.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int main (string[] args) {
//Usando la clase Dir
var d = Dir.open("/home/andy/Documentos");
string name;
while ((name = d.read_name()) != null) {
    stdout.printf("%s\n", name);
}

//Otra manera
var path = File.new_for_path("/path/sub_path/folder/");
var enumerator = path.enumerate_children(FILE_ATTRIBUTE_STANDARD_NAME, 0, null);
var fileinfo = enumerator.next_file(null);
while(fileinfo != null)
{
    stdout.printf("%s\n", fileinfo.get_name());
    fileinfo = enumerator.next_file(null);
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Además de la clase Dir también puedo utilizar otro método.